# The column 'education' is a object type. Why is this code not working? Why show the same result in both cases?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

```
len(df['education'].str.contains('Masters'))
45175

len(df['education'].str.contains('Bachelors'))
45175

df.shape
(45175, 12)
```

Someone please explain. Where's the mistake?

Comment: where (or how) is the variable `df` created please ?  presumably a dataframe ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the content of `df['education'].str.contains('Bachelors')` and `df['education'].str.contains('Masters')`. You will see that both are Pandas series of bool type: for instance, considering `df['education'].str.contains('Bachelors')`, when a given row contains `Bachelors`, it is set to `True`, otherwise, it is set to `False`, which results in the Series having the same number of rows than `df['education']`.

What you are interested into is `df[df['education'].str.contains('Bachelors')==True]` and `df[df['education'].str.contains('Masters')==True]`.